# Assigning output of SQL to variables and calling them

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables

I have an SQL output that has the below structure:

```
Name,SaleCount,ReturnCount
Prod_A,10,3
Prod_B,6,1
Prod_C,15,5
```

I am trying to have this written into a table in `Python` using `python-pptx` module.

I am assigning the output of the SQL to a variable called `output`

```
name = list(map(itemgetter(1)(0), output))
measure1 = list(map(itemgetter(1)(1), output))
measure2 = list(map(itemgetter(1)(2), output))
```

I plan to call these variables in the respective cells in the table. I am however getting an error when I try to execute the above:

```
name = list(map(itemgetter(1)(0), output))
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Expected output:

```
name = Prod_A
measure1 = 10
measure2 = 3
```

Could anyone advice how could I assign each cell in the SQL output to a variable such that I can call these later.

Update:

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql.SQL("""select name,salescount,returncount from sales where sale_date = '2018-12-30'"""))
output = cursor.fetchall()
```

Comment: Please add info about what exactly is stored inside the output variable also

Comment: @Take_Care_, I have edited with the SQL used to generate the output variable

Comment: ok so why do You pass to the `itemgetter` the `1` at first call ? I mean I think for example the names list should be like this `names = list(map(itemgetter(0), output))` when You want just one record from the `output` just get it like this `output[0][0]`.

Comment: @Take_Care_ thanks wonder why I added that extra value..